# How to filter a wordpress core function?

Tags: filters

I would like to change the text in the wp media uploader. 
I managed to find the function at the [media.php](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/post-html-upload-ui?version=3.3&file=wp-admin/includes/media.php) and i tried to using the filter to change the text like this:

```
function uploader_text() {
remove_action('post-html-upload-ui', 'media_upload_html_bypass' );
?>
<p class="upload-html-bypass hide-if-no-js">
<?php _e('mytext here'); ?>
</p>
<?php
} 
 add_filter('post-html-upload-ui', 'uploader_text');
```

But I failed to do so. What I done wrong?

**Update:** This is how I tried

The related function in wp is like this:

```
    <div id="html-upload-ui" class="hide-if-js">
            <?php do_action('pre-html-upload-ui'); ?>
                <p id="async-upload-wrap">
                    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="async-upload"><?php _e('Upload'); ?></label>
                    <input type="file" name="async-upload" id="async-upload" />
                    <?php submit_button( __( 'Upload' ), 'button', 'html-upload', false ); ?>
                    <a href="#" onclick="try{top.tb_remove();}catch(e){}; return false;"><?php _e('Cancel'); ?></a>
                </p>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php do_action('post-html-upload-ui'); ?>
            </div>


        function media_upload_html_bypass() {
            ?>
            <p class="upload-html-bypass hide-if-no-js">


<?php _e('You are using the browser&#8217;s built-in file uploader. The new WordPress uploader includes multiple file selection and drag and drop capability. <a href="#">Switch to the new uploader</a>.'); ?>
            </p>
            <?php
        }
        add_action('post-html-upload-ui', 'media_upload_html_bypass');
```

The text that i need to change is in media_upload_html_bypass() :

```
<?php _e('You are using the browser&#8217;s built-in file uploader. The new WordPress uploader includes multiple file selection and drag and drop capability. <a href="#">Switch to the new uploader</a>.'); ?>
```

So I tried :

```
function uploader_text() {

                ?>
                <p class="upload-html-bypass hide-if-no-js">
                <?php _e('here is what i want to change the text</a>.'); ?>
                </p>

                <?php

                } 
            add_filter('media_upload_html_bypass', 'uploader_text');
```

Still not working.

Comment: Which text are you exactly trying to change? A screen shot could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
function uploader_text() {
    ?>
<p class="upload-html-bypass hide-if-no-js">
    <?php _e('mytext here'); ?>
</p>
    <?php
}

remove_action('post-html-upload-ui', 'media_upload_html_bypass');
add_action('post-html-upload-ui', 'uploader_text');
```

You tried to do "remove_action" after the action already happened. That was the bug.

Comment: Nope,the original texts is still there...this only add the new text...seem the remove_action('post-html-upload-ui', 'media_upload_html_bypass'); is not working

Comment: Ok...I found out the solution. Turns out it need to add the remove_action('post-html-upload-ui', 'media_upload_html_bypass'); into admin_init....anyway thanks..

Answer (score 3):

The 'post-html-upload-ui' is an action, not a filter. So it should be: add_action instead of add_filter.